# Protractor + Cucumber + TypeScript convert to JavaScript pros and cons?

Tags: javascript, typescript, protractor

I use the Protractor + Cucumber + TypeScript framework for testing UI on Angular web application. The assertion library is Mocha Chai. 
Our CTO wants us to convert all tests and the framework from TypeScript to JavaScript.

What is your suggestion?

What are the pros and cons of Protractor + Cucumber + TypeScript and Protractor + Cucumber + JavaScript?

Any suggestion of conversion TypeScript to JavaScript?

Comment: Why does your CTO want to go from TypeScript to the typeless wild west of JavaScript?

Comment: (That said, you can just invoke `tsc` to have it emit JavaScript.)

Comment: We have an API framework that is JavaScript oriented and he thinks that it would be nice if we use JS for every automation testing framework. He doesn't want to have more languages involved in our automation testing frameworks. It is better to focus on one language than more. It is easier for colleagues who don't know TSC to jump in etc...

Comment: We have invoked tsc to emit JavaScript by typescript transpiler. Is it enough and recommended?

Comment: Well, that's how you get JavaScript from TypeScript, anyway.